# Ionic 4 Facebook Auth Error - App ID not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to implement the Facebook Authentication on my application but it's not working for iOS. On Android worker perfectly, but on iOS I get this:

> App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].

Which is not true because I do have the app id setup on the Cordova Plugin.

```
"cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "12345",
        "APP_NAME": "MyApp"
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Facing the same issue are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following keys in the string.xml(/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml) file solved the issued

```
  `<string name="fb_app_id">595121234234</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">DEMOAPP</string> `
```